# not connecting to server problem in C#

Tags: c#, connection, tcpclient

I am running a client/server application. I use a textbox to let the user type in the IP address and port. I try to connect to the server, using 127.0.0.1 and there is no problem. After that I tried using 192.168.2.102 (NAT ip address of this computer), and it fails. Any idea why?

the code I am using is: (this the the part that connects)

```
connect(string IPaddress, int port)
{
    TcpCLient connection = new TcpClient();
    connection.Connect(IPaddress, port);
}
```

I checked with debug, it DOES use the right IPaddress and port.
Firewall should allow it to connect. It's weird.

**EDIT:**
I think I know the problem. At the server side, I use

```
_listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 8001);
```

And I think that's the reason why it only accepts connections from 127.0.0.1. But then, what should I use instead? I just want any connection from any IP with this port.

Comment: You will probably need to include more information about the failure... what exception do you get? what happens?

Comment: "192.168.2.102:8001 Connection was not possible because the destination computer actively rejected it".

Comment: Are you sure the specified port is not in use? Try making the same connection to the 192.* address and allow the system to choose a port for you. See if you get a different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are specifying IPAddress.Loopback, then only connections to 127.0.0.1 will work. Replace it with [IPAddress.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx) to tell your server to listen on all interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the only circumstance I've ever seen return `Connection was not possible because the destination computer actively rejected it` is when there is actually nothing listening for connections at the specified address and port... or there is a firewall.

You may want to verify with a `tracert` that `192.168.2.102` actually points where you think it does. Another option is to use `telnet` from the command line to connect to the address and port if you really suspect there is a problem in your code (although I cannot see that apply here).

**Addendum:**
Is there any other application that can successfully make a connection to that specific IP address on that same machine?